# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x8009030D): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized at System.Net.SSPIWrapper

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I have searched the above topic on google and seems like everyone is talking about file read permission. But in my case, it's not permission, let me explain below.

I have successfully built the `X509Certificate2`, and I have printed them to file, and checked the `NotBefore`, `NotAfter`, `CN`, and `Thumbprint`, all matching my SSL.

The way I am building is using `pfx` file directly, so no need for permission to talk to IIS.

Everything works in local, I can have SSL connection. But not in server

Comment: 2 things. First, did you store the private key with the certificate? Second, Have you tried running the program as an administrator? This is sometimes an access issue.

Comment: Nobody can guess what is "not in server". Do type enough words (and possibly use diagrams/screenshots as well) to describe things clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue.

in IIS, each application has its individual access.

To fix this issue, go to Application Pools in IIS, and change the Identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity to NetWork.

The reason for fail is that the ApplicationPoolIdentity does not have network access under IIS.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that to solve an error with similar symptoms it is necessary to set the Identity to LocalSystem in order to properly use the certificate in the Local machine store.

Comment: Are you sure that you are providing a solution to the problem described at the top of this page? To me it seems possible that you have a different problem (i.e. in Local scope instead of OPs Network scope). Consider creating a separate question and to provide this as solution there (after deleting it here). But you might be able to make this a solution, if you can show how the problem can be generalised, e.g. to "mismatching identity" with a solution "match the configured identity to the scope of your setup" and thereby aboid two "basically same questions".

Comment: Any way, I tried to [edit] and help you make this more according to [answer]. If I failed that (e.g. because of totally misunderstanding the question and the answer.... in that case please accept my apology) feel free to undo my edits and improve it yourself. Consider taking the [tour].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).